# Jasypt: how secure master password?

Tags: java, spring, jasypt

Colleagues, i used Jasypt in my spring-boot project (standalone jar running on Windows).
I need to pass master password via command line to run jar . 
It looks like:

`java -jar -Djasypt.encryptor.password=masterpass app-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar`

So anybody can see `masterpass` via Windows Task Manager:
[image]

How to secure this masterpass?

I have found an example where master password is stored in Windows Environment variable, but, it seems, no good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally very difficult to hide anything when running on the client's workstation. At the end - when passwords/keys are encrypted, you need to store the password or private key somewhere anyway :/

You can encode/encrypt  data to make it more difficult, but once the binaries and configuration reside at the client side, you won't stop a dedicated adversary easily.

If you at least don't want to show the password outside (in the environment or command line) - how about reading the master password from a file and setting a system property in the `main` before running anything else?

(please let me know if it worked)

Answer (score 0):

At least you should not provide the master-password via commandline option as if other users have access to the machine they can retrieve it from the process list.

Instead provide it via a separate configuration file. So in case you are using spring-boot and have your regular env properties in config/application.properties then simply add a config/application.yml file with just the master-password and keep that only on the machine with only user permissions (chmod go -rxw). See e.g. here:
https://github.com/oasp/oasp4j/wiki/guide-configuration#password-encryption

Everything else from the installation may come from your git repo where people with access only see encrypted passwords but can not decrypt unless they have the master-password what they do not have if they have no physical access to the productive machine. Operators may provide the passwords only encrypted to the dev team so they never know the actual passwords. DevOps gurus might not like this but keeping the passwords secret to a minimum number of admins is generally good for security.